# Do Primitive Types in C++ have destructors?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, smart-pointers

This question comes from me trying to understand the motivation for smart pointers where you make a wrapper class around the pointer so that you could add a custom destructor. Do pointers (and ints, bools, doubles, etc.) not have a destructor?

Comment: C++ is a multiparadigm language, which means that not everything has to be a class.

Comment: @dandan78 Are you're saying that primitive types are not classes thus don't have destructors?

Comment: @JoshuaSegal Primitive types are *not* classes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl primitive types don't exist (much like the spoon). Instead, C++ has non-class types, which are not classes because they are not class types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive types (and compounds thereof) have *trivial destructors*. These don't do anything, and have special wording that allows them to be skipped altogether in some cases.

This, however, is orthogonal to why C++ has smart pointers. A raw pointer is non-owning: it points at another object, but does not affect its lifetime. Smart pointers, on the other hand, own (or share ownership of) their pointee, tying its lifetime to their own. This is what is implemented inside, among other special functions, their destructor.

Comment: so what does the trivial destructor do exactly? Does it really not do anything?

Comment: @Joshua yep, that's it. It's mainly there for consistency, but is specified to be a no-op.

Comment: That's interesting! Tying this in to dandan78 comment, would you say that primitive types are classes or another paradigm as dandan78 said? If it was a different paradigm then I wouldn't see why c++ would go to the trouble of making a fake destructor.

Comment: This is incorrect with regards to destructors. See my answer for correct explanation.

Answer (score 17):

Technically speaking, non-class types (C++ term for what often called 'primitive type' in layman words) do not have destructors.

C++ Standard only speaks of real destructors in context of classes, see [class.dtor] in C++ standard. Aside from that, C++ also allows to call a destructor on a non-class object using the same notation, i.e. following code is valid:

```
void foo(int z) {
    using T = int;
    z.~T();
}
```

This is called 'pseudo-destructor' and exists exclusively to allow writing generic templated code to deal in the same manner with class and non-class types. This call does nothing at all. This syntax is defined in [expr.prim.id] in C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given here so far, since C++20 the pseudo-destructor call on a non-class object will always end its lifetime. Consequently accessing the object's value after the call will have undefined behavior. This does not mean however that the compiler has to emit any code for such a call. It still effectively does nothing.

Comment: Can you explain more about ending its lifetime?

Comment: @thedemons Objects in C++ have a lifetime. With few exceptions they can only be used as long as they are in their lifetime. The lifetime begins when storage for the object is obtained and initialization, if any, is completed. Lifetime of a class type object typically ends when its destructor is called, while lifetime of non-class types ends e.g. with the pseudo-destructor call or at the end of their storage duration (e.g. when the end of the scope of an automatic storage duration variable is reached).

Comment: @thedemons See https://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1 and following for the details about lifetime and https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr#call-5.sentence-2 for the effect of the pseudo-destructor call.

Answer (score 0):

No, pointers don't have destructors. An object referenced through a plain old pointer has to be `delete`d to avoid memory leaks, and the object's destructor is called then, but the compiler won't call `delete` automatically, even when a pointer goes out of scope - what if another part of your program also had a pointer to the same object?

Smart pointers aren't about calling a custom destructor, they're about ensuring that things get cleaned up automatically when they go out of scope. This 'cleaning up' might be deleting owned objects, `free`ing any `malloc`ed memory, closing files, releasing locks, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Destructors are used to free the resources that an object may have used.

For pointers, you don't need delete if you are not allocating new memory from the heap.

C and C++ have two ways to store a variable: stack and heap.

Stack is for static memory, and the compiler takes care of that. Heap is for dynamic memory, and you have to take care of this if you are using it.

When you do primitive type declarations, stack memory is allocated for the variables.

When you use `new` to declare an object, this object is stored on the heap, which you need to delete it when you are finishing using it, or it would be a memory leak.

Basically, you only need `delete` if you new something.

Comment: `c++` does not call it a stack or heap however. As far as the language is concerned these are an implementation detail.

Comment: @drescherjm c and c++ use the same terminology when referring to static and dynamic memory

Comment: "You don't need a destructor if you are not allocating new memory from the heap" - destructors are not only useful for freeing memory. A class may do lots of things in its destructor that can make sense regardless of whether the object is using automatic storage or the free store.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Got it. Edited.

Comment: what does this has to do with non-class types destruction ???