# Emplace with primitive types

Tags: c++, stl, destructor, primitive-types

Since in C++, primitive types destructors do nothing [[Do Primitive Types in C++ have destructors?]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60007687/18272383), is it safe to rely on the value of `int a` to be the same **after a call to `queue::emplace`**? Specifically,

```cpp
queue<int> q;
int a = 5;
q.emplace(a);
// is a==5 here?
```

Perhaps the first question would also answer this, though for this example:

```
queue<pair<int,int>> q;
int a = 1, b = 2;
q.emplace(a,b);
// is a == 1, b == 2?
```

Comment: `q.emplace(a);` is okay, `a` will still be 5.  `q.emplace(move(a));` is also okay, because `int` *move* semantics are the same as its *copy* semantics.  (However, a *rude* (technical term) function being passed a `move(a)` might futz with it.  Hard to see any justification for that, but still, it might futz with it.  Rudely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in the shown code are all lvalues.

For the emplaced primitive type, as is the case here: an lvalue that gets passed to `emplace()` does not get modified. If the container contains a class with a constructor, that emplace ends up invoking, for a "well-behaved" constructor the parameter won't get modified whether it's an `int` or a discrete class instance.

The only time something that gets passed to `emplace()` typically gets altered, in some way, would be if that "something" is a movable rvalue, and the corresponding constructor parameter is an rvalue, and the constructor moves the rvalue somewhere else, leaving the original parameter in some valid, but unspecified state. Or, if "something" is a non-const lvalue, and the constructor intentionally modifies it, but that would be rather rude (not well-behaved).

This wouldn't be the case for primitive types, in any case.