# What does the destructor of primitive types actually do?

Tags: c++

I recently came across this weird piece of code on the internet:

```cpp
typedef int int_t;
int val = 55;
val.~int_t();

printf("%d\n", val);
```

The assembly produced under x86-64 gcc 5.1:

```
sub     rsp, 8
mov     esi, 55
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0  ;"%d\n"
xor     eax, eax
call    printf
xor     eax, eax
add     rsp, 8
ret
```

It turns out the `.~int_t()` is never called. How is it valid code?

Also, if primitive values are located on the stack do they even have a destructor? If yes, what do their destructors actually do?

Comment: "Also, if literal types are located on the stack do they even have a destructor?" Types aren't "located" anywhere, *values* are; and by default, any value of any type can be located either on the stack or in the heap unless you take *explicit* (and tricky) steps to prevent one or the other. Being on the stack or the heap has nothing to do with having a destructor or not; destructors are called implicitly when objects leave the stack - **that's the point** of RAII.

Comment: As far as I know, primitive types don't have destructors.  They have a do-nothing _pseudo-destructor_ which exists to permit templated code to be legal when used with primitive types. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60007687/1563833)

Comment: What do you expect `~int_t` to do, if it were called? Can you explain, in your own words, what this means to you, and what this destructor should do?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't expect it to do anything, it just weird that it even has a destructor

Comment: @Wyck that question is a clear duplicate target, then.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sort of.  The question isn't asking about the standard.  It's asking about the actual behaviour of x86-64 gcc 5.1.  I assume the answer is _it does nothing_.  The linked answer probably justifies why.

Comment: Thanks @Wyck, KarlKnechtel, I only searched for 'literal', so I didn't see that question, closing for duplicate

Comment: @thedemons -- "weird that it even has a destructor" -- back in the olden days it didn't. But when you're writing code that handles object creation and destruction and you want to use templates, you need to be able to write `~T()` even when `T` is an integer type. Yes, you could write specializations for all of the built-in types that don't call the destructor, but that's tedious and error-prone. But `~int_t()` is, indeed, weird.